# The grammar of "っていうの"

Tags: grammar

> でもわたしに何が**できるの** ―― ああ、ほんとうに１ドル８７セントで何が**できるっていうの**？

I want to know the grammatical function of "っていう" in the second sentence and how it works. It seems to me that both of the sentences essentially mean "何ができるの".

The quotation is from [賢者の贈り物 (結城浩訳)](http://www.hyuki.com/trans/magi.html)

Comment: should I delete it?

Comment: No you shouldn't.

Comment: ^ No you don't have to じゃなくて？